# error package docker-ce requires container-selinux = 2.9 centos 7

Tags: docker

**Command:** yum -y install docker-ce

**Result:**

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker-ce.x86_64 0:18.06.0.ce-3.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2.9 for package: docker-ce-18.06.0.ce-3.el7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: docker-ce-18.06.0.ce-3.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2.9
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Comment: Look at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479406/error-package-docker-ce-requires-container-selinux-2-9-centos-7/52723620#52723620

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolved with installing container-selinux-2.9 dependency with following command:

```
sudo yum install ftp://bo.mirror.garr.it/1/slc/centos/7.1.1503/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: `yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libseccomp-2.3.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm` is also required in my case it was asking for libseccomp > 2.3

Comment: What is the "bo.mirror.garr.it"? Why can we trust it?

Comment: same for me as well

Answer (score 5):

Use below link to install **container-selinux** from a trust able source

```
sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.55-1.el7.noarch.rpm
```

#### Steps to install Docker-CE on RHEL 7.5

https://github.com/dineshsood/dockers/wiki

Comment: `sudo yum install -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch.rpm` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

This `docker-ce` version worked for me:

```
   sudo yum -y install docker-ce-cli.x86_64 1:19.03.5-3.el7
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can enable the Extras repository in the path:

```
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

Comment: though a solution has been found i think this can be elaborated a little bit :)

Comment: You duplicate the existing text (so the file is twice as big) and change the title in square brackets to, say, "CentOS extras" and change the URL so ".../os/..." becomes ".../extras/..."

Comment: my aws ec2 instance (aws linux 2) doesn't even have this file

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable CentOS "extras" repository.

Here's how I did it:

1. Open `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`
2. Duplicate contents of the file, so it becomes twice as long
3. Replace `/os/` in the URL with `/extras/`
4. Change the section title in square brackets

E.g.:

```
[CentOS-Base]
name=CentOS 7 Base Mirror
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

[CentOS-Extras]
name=CentOS 7 Extras
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

Then try installing docker again

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `--nogpgcheck` to the selected answer de to an error

`Public key for container-selinux-2.9-4.el7.noarch.rpm is not installed`